# Impressão de PDF Direto na Impressora em java

Tags: java, impressão

Então, preciso imprimir um PDF diretamente na impressora, por que  necessito imprimir Notas Fiscais.Se eu utilizar  esta forma `Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop().print("Caminho do arquivo")`
ele imprime normalmente na primeira vez, porém abre o adobe junto e o adobe fecha o documento e daí quando vou imprimir novamente, ele "buga" e imprime tudo que está no PDF extremamente pequeno.E a idéia é que imprima de forma direta e no tamanho correto do papel.

Possuo essas 3 impressoras :`Bematech MP 4200  TH, Bematech MP 4000 TH e MP2500TH.`
Abaixo está a forma como eu aprendi a imprimir diretamente pela impressora.

```
PrintService iPadrao = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

try {
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\EX-PHP\\Documents\\TestePDF2\\vai.pdf");

    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, docFlavor, null);
    DocPrintJob p = iPadrao.createPrintJob();
    p.print(doc, null);
} catch (PrintException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

O PDF em questão contém uma nota fiscal que contém um QR code.
Também tentei com PDFRenderer, e com alguns códigos que encontrei na internet mas sem sucesso,pode ser algum erro nos códigos ou algo que esteja faltando.

Comment: Se você usar `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF`, o que acontece?

Comment: entao ali foi só um erro meu mesmo, mas colocando tudo certo e com o flavor PDF ele da invalid flavor.Preciso que imprima direto pois é pra imprimir nota fiscal.

Comment: Qual o modelo da sua impressora?

Comment: tenho 2, Bematech MP 4200  TH, Bematech MP 4000 TH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção para trabalhar com `PDF` é utilizar a biblioteca [`Apache PDFBox`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) que irá extrair o conteúdo do seu arquivo e permitir que seja impresso:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

  PDDocument documento = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/Users/EX-PHP/Documents/TestePDF2/vai.pdf"));
  PrintService servico = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(documento));
  job.setPrintService(servico);
  job.print();
  documento.close();
}
```

As dependências para utilização do `Apache PDFBox` podem ser encontradas na sessão [`Dependencies`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html) do site. Para este exemplo será necessário [`Apache Commons Logging`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) e o [`fontbox`](http://www-us.apache.org/dist/pdfbox/2.0.7/fontbox-2.0.7.jar).

Caso esteja usando `Maven` utilize a seguinte importação de dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Resposta para pergunta similar no `Stack Overflow`: [**Print a PDF file using PrinterJob in Java**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38273386/3388148).

Comment: Eu baixei o jar  coloquei certinho la e usei este mesmo código, e me retornou esse erro `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory`

Comment: @TheJ adicione a biblioteca [Apache Commons Logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) ao seu projeto também.

Comment: adicionei e agora voltou essa exceção `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fontbox/type1/DamagedFontException`

Comment: @TheJ adicione o [fontbox](http://www-us.apache.org/dist/pdfbox/2.0.7/fontbox-2.0.7.jar)

Comment: Funcionou , obrigado ontem eu tava loco de cansado procurando com umas 20 aba aberta olhando e re-olhando kd link e testando tudo pra ver se funfava e não conseguia e eu nem sequer passei perto desse PDFBox.Quanto a explicação desses 2 ultimos jars que eu adicionei, eu precisaria criar outro post?

Comment: @TheJ não, eu vou incluir na resposta

Comment: Tranquilo, muito obrigado, salvou meu ganha pão.

Comment: Minha duvida agora seria quanto ao alinhamento das coisas para imprimir.Pois se eu definir tudo como ALLIGN.CENTER ou ALLIGN.MIDDLE a impressora imprime um pequeno pedaço, e em branco ainda. Abro outro post?

Comment: @TheJ Sim, a dúvida agora é outra